# Auto populate region picklist field when state of picklist field is selected

Tags: configuration

Auto populate region(East,West,North,South)) picklist field when state(ca,TX, LA...) of picklist field is selected.

I have a state picklist Field with list of states, i created one more picklist Field Region(East,West,North,South) whenever I select state corresponding region picklist field should get populated automatically in the region field.
Can any one please help me with this without coding .

Comment: [dependent picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Step1 :- First to create the two field as API Name State__c and Region__c of type picklist on object which you want

Step2:-  click on State__c field then click on New button in Field Dependencies, 
[image]
Step3:- Select the depandent field as Region__c
[image]
Step4:- Than Select Region value of corrosponding State,
[image]
than click on Save Button.

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thank you for detail solution, I tried this one but problem is whenever i select state field, region field was not auto populates region instead it is populating none then i have go manually click then i can select region (east,west,north,south)...Please let me know why it is happening...i dont have to create state field as it is already exist in my object but i created region picklist and followed all your steps

Comment: In above solution region field is dependent on the state field and when you select the state value from given picklist value then coresponding region value is populated in the region field. if you want to select only state field value then you should use workflow